# Angular pagination error - Type 'T | null' is not assignable to type 'T'

Tags: angular

In Angular-13 project, I am implementing Server-side pagination. I have this model:

pagination.ts:

```
export interface Pagination {
  currentPage: number;
  itemsPerPage: number;
  totalItems: number;
  totalPages: number;
}

export class PaginatedResult<T> {
  result!: T;
  pagination!: Pagination;
}
```

Then I have writtent a function as paginationHelper in the core module:.

paginationHelper:

```
import { PaginatedResult } from "src/app/shared/models/pagination";

export function getPaginatedResult<T>(url: any, params: any, http: HttpClient) {
    const paginatedResult: PaginatedResult<T> = new PaginatedResult<T>();

    return http.get<T>(url, { observe: 'response', params }).pipe(
      map(response => {
        paginatedResult.result = response.body;
        if (response.headers.get('Pagination') !== null) {
          paginatedResult.pagination = JSON.parse(response.headers.get('Pagination') || '{}');
        }
        return paginatedResult;
      })
    );
  }

  export function getPaginationHeaders(pageNumber: number, pageSize: number){
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.append('pageNumber', pageNumber.toString());
    params = params.append('pageSize', pageSize.toString());
    return params;
  }
```

I am to eventually utilise the paginationHelper in the TeacherService:

```
getAll(pageNumber, pageSize){
  let params = getPaginationHeaders(pageNumber, pageSize);
  return getPaginatedResult<Teacher[]>(this.baseUrl+'Teacher/get-pagination', params, this.http);
}
```

However, I got this error in paginationHelper:

> Type 'T | null' is not assignable to type 'T'.
> 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T | null'.

paginatedResult!.result is highlighted.

How do I get this resolved?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your problem come from the exclamation mark on your variables definition. The exclamation mark is the not null operator.

This should work instead:

```
result: T;
pagination: Pagination;
```

Comment: I removed the exclamation, but the problem is still there